hitTest() never works (AS2)
Screenshot
What have I done wrong? No matter what I do with the movie clips, it never goes to the next frame. [Flash 8]
onClipEvent (load) {
speed = 10;
grav = o;
}
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
\_y += grav;
if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
\_x -= speed;
}
if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
\_x += speed;
}
if (\_root.object1.hitTest(\_root.object2)) {
gotoAndStop(2);
}
}

I tried to get a movieClip to go left or right with arrow keys, and then when it hitTested object2 it should move to frame 2, but the hittest doesn't work.

Before hitTest line put trace(_root.object1); and trace(_root.object2); to see if you are addressing these MovieClips correctly.
